# Get a substring in a '/' delimited string in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this string as value of a node:

```
/TAG3/Tag 3 Value/TAG2/Tag2 Value/Tag2 Value 2/Tag 2 value 3/TAG4/Tag4 value/TAG1/Tag 1 value/Tag1 value 2/
```

and if I need to re-arrange it according to TAG number like below

```
/TAG1/Tag 1 value/Tag1 value 2/TAG2/Tag2 Value/Tag2 Value 2/Tag 2 value 3/TAG3/Tag 3 Value/TAG4/Tag4 value
```

or break it down by tags like this

```
/TAG1/Tag 1 value/Tag1 value 2/
/TAG2/Tag2 Value/Tag2 Value 2/Tag 2 value 3/
/TAG3/Tag 3 Value/
/TAG4/Tag4 value/
```

each string should start and end with the '/', and must jave a keyword (e.g.'TAG1') and values (e.g. 'Tag1 value') combination, values can be multiple but keyword must only be one

Is it possible to do this in XSLT 1.0 by the way?

I have this Input XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn-sample">
  <CustomerRecord>
    <Statement>
      <StmtId>123</StmtId>
      <StmtDate>2013-08-16</StmtDate>
      <AcctNumber>123456789</AcctNumber>
      <Balance>
        <Type>OP</Type>
        <Amount>1.00</Amount>
        <CreditOrDebit>DR</CreditOrDebit>
        <Date>2013-08-15</Date>
      </Balance>
      <Balance>
        <Type>CL</Type>
        <Amount>2.00</Amount>
        <CreditOrDebit>CR</CreditOrDebit>
        <Date>2013-08-16</Date>
      </Balance>
      <Balance>
        <Type>FW</Type>
        <Amount>3.00</Amount>
        <CreditOrDebit>CR</CreditOrDebit>
        <Date>2013-08-17</Date>
      </Balance>
      <Entry>
        <Amount>7778.70</Amount>
        <CreditOrDebit>DR</CreditOrDebit>
        <EntryDtls>
          <TransactionDetails>
            <Parties>
              <!--Details can come like this format--> 
              <Customer>
                <Name>Customer 1 Name</Name>
                <Address>Address Line 1</Address>
              </Customer>
              <CustomerAcct>
                <AcctName>Account Name 1</AcctName>
                <AcctNumber>12345677</AcctNumber>
              </CustomerAcct>
              <!--Or this-->
              <CustDetails>/CUST/Customer 1 Name/Address Line 1/ACCT/Account Name 1/12345677/BANK/Bank Name/Bank Address/</CustDetails>
            </Parties>
            <AddlInfo>
              <Info1>Info 1</Info1>
              <Info1>Info 2</Info1>
              <Info1>Info 3</Info1>
            </AddlInfo>
          </TransactionDetails>
        </EntryDtls>
      </Entry>
    </Statement>
  </CustomerRecord>
</Document>
```

That should have this output for the Description tag CStatement/CStatementLine/Description:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root> <!--should have no attribute-->
  <CStatement>
    <CStatementId>123</CStatementId>
    <CStatementDate>2013-08-16</CStatementDate>
    <AccountNumber>123456789</AccountNumber>
    <OpeningBalance>-1.00</OpeningBalance>
    <ClosingBalance>2.00</ClosingBalance>
    <CStatementLine>
      <DebitOrCredit>DR</DebitOrCredit>
      <Amount>-7778.70</Amount>
      <!--values below will be coming from 
        <CustDetails>/CUST/Customer 1 Name/Address Line 1/ACCT/Account Name 1/12345677/BANK/Bank Name/Bank Address/</CustDetails> if 
        <Customer>
          <Name>Customer 1 Name</Name>
          <Address>Address Line 1</Address>
        </Customer>
        <CustomerAcct>
          <AcctName>Account Name 1</AcctName>
          <AcctNumber>12345677</AcctNumber>
        </CustomerAcct>
      is not existing-->
      <CustomerName>Customer 1 Name</CustomerName>
      <CustomerAddress>Address Line 1</CustomerAddress>
      <CustAccountName>Account Name</CustAccountName>
      <CustomerBankAccount>12345677</CustomerBankAccount>
      <Description>CUST+Customer 1 Name+Address Line 2+ACCT+Account Name 1+12345677+ADDL+Info 1+Info 2+Info 3</Description>
    </CStatementLine>
  </CStatement>
</Root>
```

Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Possible - yes. Easy - no. XSLT is designed to process XML-structured data, not arbitrary strings. In any case, I suggest you add a **real** example to your question, because your abstract example is somewhat ambiguous (what determines if a word is a tag or a value?) and also obviously incorrectly formed with regards to spaces. Your desired output is also not clear: do you want to output a text file? If not, why not take this opportunity to structure the data as proper XML?

Comment: Which XSLT 1.0 processor, BTW? You might benefit from some EXSLT extension functions here, if your processor supports them.

Comment: we only use VS2010 because we cannot install other third party extensions, by the way edited my post

Comment: Is there a known list of tags (CUST, ACCT, BANK,...) that can appear in this string?

Comment: yes, (CUST, ACCT, BANK,...) are known tags to name a few and whatever follows those tags + '/'  are values until it reached the next tag which starts with '/'

Comment: And can you follow the order of tags as they appear in the input? Or must you rearrange the order?

Comment: I must rearrange the order, so my problem right now is getting the specific TAG with value/s so that I can process them separately, and al;so I have to put them in the description tags with a different delimiter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this may be too complicated to answer comfortably within the confines of a forum answer. Still, I believe the solution to the three main problems here:

1. extracting the values from the given string; while
2. assigning a tag to each value; and
3. sorting the resulting values

can be shown.

Given the following **test input**:

```
<input>
    <CustDetails>/ACCT/Account Name 1/12345677/BANK/Bank Name/Bank Address/CUST/Customer 1 Name/Address Line 1/</CustDetails>
</input>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:variable name="tags" select="'|CUST|BANK|ACCT|'"/>

<xsl:template match="input">
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="values">
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
            <!-- remove the opening slash -->
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring(CustDetails, 2, string-length(CustDetails))"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- output -->
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($values)/value">
            <!-- sort by position of @tag in $tags -->
            <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($tags, concat('|', @tag, '|')))" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'/'"/>
    <xsl:param name="tag"/>
    <xsl:if test="$text">
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before($text, $delimiter)"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($tags, concat('|', $token, '|'))">
                <!-- new tag -->
                <value tag="{$token}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
                </value>
                 <!-- recursive call -->              
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="tag" select="$token"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <value tag="{$tag}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$token"/>
                </value>
                 <!-- recursive call -->
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="tag" select="$tag"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
  <value tag="CUST">CUST</value>
  <value tag="CUST">Customer 1 Name</value>
  <value tag="CUST">Address Line 1</value>
  <value tag="BANK">BANK</value>
  <value tag="BANK">Bank Name</value>
  <value tag="BANK">Bank Address</value>
  <value tag="ACCT">ACCT</value>
  <value tag="ACCT">Account Name 1</value>
  <value tag="ACCT">12345677</value>
</output>
```

You just need to modify the output and instead of copying the value as is, place it in a text string.

Comment: is it possible not to use exsl? :)

Comment: @zyberjock If it is, I don't want to go there. I am quite sure your processor supports either `exsl:node-set()` or an equivalent (I don't know of any processor that doesn't).

Comment: I have edited the output like this<xsl:if test ="@tag='CUST'">
                <xsl:if test ="position()=1">
                  <!--Display the tag on the first occurence /CUST/-->
                  <xsl:value-of select ="concat('/', @tag)"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select ="concat('/', text())"/>
              </xsl:if>, because for example i want to get just the data for CUST which will output to CUST/Customer 1 Name/Address Line 1

Comment: @zyberjock Have you noticed the edit to my post? I believe the output is now easier to handle. -- In any case, please don't post code in comments - it's unreadable.

Comment: thanks, that nailed it, sorry bout my comment wont happen again

Comment: I have one question regarding this, is there a way for me to test whether any of the given keyword does not exist in the test input?

Comment: @zyberjock Yes, but not easily. Do you mean test one specific keyword, or all of them?

Comment: yes for example i have this test input <CustDetails>Juan Dela Cruz</CustDetails>, it should return false because It does not contain any of my Keywords

Comment: @zyberjock In this example, `<xsl:value-of select="boolean(exsl:node-set($values)/value[string(@tag)])"/>` will return "false".

Comment: thanks for the very much needed help, got it working :)